# Token not returned: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Tags: tokens, nft, error, polygon, games

Polygon Weth token not returned after failed transaction.
I press "buy" again the Hero in Idle Mystic game after refreshing it since it says failed in metamask. The token payment for the failed transaction was not returned. Please help

Comment: There is no way we can answer this question. Maybe a transaction hash could help explain your transaction.

Comment: Can you include more details? transaction id, address involved, wallet used. A reverted transaction will undo all effects, only the transaction fee will be paid.